# MySql vs PostgreSQL with EF Core connectors

Tags: entity-framework, entity-framework-core, entity-framework-6

I will start working on a project using asp.net core and EF Core , and i need to use either MySql or PostgreSQL, and i want to know Which one of them have the most mature connector, also which one will support the Verion 6 of EF

Comment: Both are good and cover 99% of cases. I prefer PostgreSQL for no reason.

Comment: I suggest PostgreSQL, it is better supported by EF Core.

Answer (score 1):

I suggest PostgreSQL with EF Core.

This statistics also give you hint on this, as you can see the usage of the 2: (as of 2023 Jan)

**PostgreSQL:**

https://www.nuget.org/packages/Npgsql.EntityFrameworkCore.PostgreSQL
Total 173.4M

**MySql:**

https://www.nuget.org/packages/MySql.EntityFrameworkCore
Total 2.0M
https://www.nuget.org/packages/Pomelo.EntityFrameworkCore.MySql
Total 33.4M